# Scroll Bar with Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Here is my function:

```
    $("#Buyer").live('change', function(){ 
    var empkey = $("#Buyer").val(); 
    if (empkey > 0) {   
        callPreloader({ 
            target: '#T1',
            message: 'Loading results.',
            url: '/xxx',
            method: 'get',
            data: {Buyer:empkey}, 
            callback: function(){ 
                $('.datatable').dataTable( {
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "scrollY": "800px",
                    "scrollCollapse": true,
                    "paging": false
                  });
            }
        }) 
    } 
});
```

I am trying to get something like the scroll bar at this link: http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html

When I refresh I do not have a scroll bar. It just looks like it did before adding the scrollY, scrollCollapse and paging. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
callback: function(){ 
                $('.datatable').dataTable( {
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "sScrollY": "530px",
                    "sScrollCollapse": true,
                    "sPaging": false
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Custom style for your own Like this :

give the table tag a class

```
<table class='scrollable'>
<tr></tr>
.......
......
</table>
```

and give the table fixed "height" in your  CSS file :

```
.scrollable{
   height: 200px;
   overflow-x: scroll
}
```

try it and let me know if it works :)

Comment: I tried something like that and didn't have any luck with it.

Comment: When I inspect the element in shows the height of 200 px but the actual table isn't any shorter.